# Regexp searches that repeatedly cover expressions

Tags: regular-expressions, search, replace

I'm just going through an old Latex-text I've written and wanted to use regexp-replace to make any pair of brackets containing at least one other pair of brackets into a `\left(.*\right)`-expression. After some trying, I came up with this pair of regexp-replace expressions:

```
(\([^)]*?\)( → \\left(\1(
```

```
)\([^(]*?\)) → )\1\\right)
```

So the program should take any two most adjecent opening brackets that have between them no closing bracket and put a `\left` before the first bracket, and similar for closing brackets. However, there seems to be the problem that, if in such an expression as the first above regexp the second opening bracket starts a balanced expression that again contains other brackets, it still isn't considered as the first opening bracket of another such regexp because it is already in one regexp. Thus, for instance, the following line

```
S( (Id(A)_{γ} Id(B) )_{↑ δ} Id(C) )
```

is transformed to the following expression after applying the two commands:

```
S\left( (Id(A)_{γ} Id(B) \right)_{↑ δ} Id(C) \right)
```

As one can see, there are two `\right` inserted but only one `\left` because the second opening bracket is already covered the first time the "insert-\left"-regexp is applied, whereas the dual statement is not true for the closing brackets because there is one pair of brackets between the last bracket and the other bracket closing an expression that contains other brackets. So an additional `\left` should be inserted before the second opening bracket of the statement.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior? So that the second opening bracket of the above line is tested again on whether or not it is the first bracket in a regexp such as the "insert-\left"-regexp?

Comment: Can you anchor the second regexp to e.g. the trailing dollar sign: `)\([^(]*?\))\$ → )\1\\right)$` ?

Comment: @NickD No, I want to add `\left` also to brackets that are not next to dollar signs.

Comment: Maybe your example is too simple to capture the general case or maybe I don't understand it: should there be two \left-\right pairs (i.e. a \left is missing) or only one (i.e. the first \right is extraneous)?

Comment: @NickD Two. Before the second opening bracket a second `\left` should be inserted.

Comment: OK - maybe you should edit the question and clarify what is expected. FWIW,  you certainly cannot do what you want with "standard" regexps, although you might be able to do something with "extended" regexps (all modern regexp engines provide *some* extensions) but it's not at all clear to me that it is possible (and even if it is, it probably will not be easy).